# How to handle optimization problems when optimization variable is matrix?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Suppose we have the following optimization problem

$$
\min_{0\preceq M \preceq I} y^TMy
$$
where $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix. Notice that the optimization variable is matrix.

> Is there any algebraically way to handle this in terms of $M$?

When we write it as the standard form we have the following

$$
\min y^TMy
$$
$$
\text{s.t.}\,\,\,\,\,\, {g_1(M)=-M \preceq 0 }
$$
$$
\text{s.t.}\,\,\,\,\,\, {g_2(M)=I-M \preceq 0 }
$$
which is a matrix inequality. If it were vector, it was doable but what would we do when they are in matrix form.

I want to write the first order optimality condition using Lagrangian in terms of gradient of $g_1(M)$ and $g_2(M)$ but the gradient in terms of $M$ is $I$ and $-I$.
The following answer explains it using different view.

[What is the KKT condition for constraint $M \preceq I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980940/what-is-the-kkt-condition-for-constraint-m-preceq-i)

I want a method that ties these to views together.

I want to know the general case. I want to handle it directly in terms of M.

I will appreciate, If you introduce me any reference that addresses this issue.

Comment: Doesn't $M=0$ solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic is discussed in [Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).   See section 5.9.

The key idea here is that you need an appropriate inner product associated with the conic inequality.  For positive semidefiniteness constraints, the associated inner product is $\langle A, B \rangle=\mbox{tr}(A^{T}B)$.  The Lagrange multiplier for the conic constraint must be a positive semidefinite matrix $\Lambda \succeq 0$ rather than a scalar.   All of the theory for scalar constraints carries over in a straight-forward way to this more general setting.