Is there a way to efficiently estimate the maximum singular value of a symmetric, non-constant matrix (given some constraints)?
Given a symmetric n x n  matrix - whose entries are
polynomial functions (let's say of degree 1 but ideally higher degrees as well) of n variables $x_0 ... x_n$ - is there some established method to estimate the max possible singular value of the tensor over all x_i's bounded by the unit hypercube?
The only way I can think of, unfortunately, is grid search - sampling $\mathbf x$ and calculating largest singular values.

These may be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367232/formula-for-the-derivative-of-singular-values https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588473/derivatives-of-eigenvalues https://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jca/jca03/jca03011.pdf
