# Eigenvalue perturbation of hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, perturbation-theory

For $\rho$ and $A$ hermitian matrices, $t$ a scalar parameter, $f_i(\rho)$ denoting the $i-$th eigenvalue of the matrix $\rho$ and $|x_i\rangle$ the normalized eigenvector of $\rho$ corresponding to $f_i(\rho)$, does the following hold in the limit $t \to 0$

$f_i(\rho + tA)=f_i(\rho) + tr \{A |x_i\rangle\langle x_i|\}t +{\mathcal{O}}(t^2)$

I tried to find a reference for this but couldn't. Does anyone know whether this holds true?

Comment: If you assume that the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors are differentiable, the statement follows easily from implicit differentiation. See [user7530's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2588484) for instance.

Comment: @user1551 thank you for your answer! I assume that the spectrum is non-degenerate, but I don't see how the statement would follow from implicit differentiation. 
Also (maybe this is a stupid question), when you mentioned the continuity of the eigenvalues in the first Gerschgorin disk, why do you say that the eignevalue must be $\lambda_1(\hat{\rho}_t)$?

Comment: (1) user7530's answer already offers a proof based on implicit differentiation. (2) When $j\ne1$, we have $\lim_{t\to0}\lambda_j(\widehat\rho_t)=\lambda_j(\rho)\ne\lambda_1(\rho)$. Therefore the only eigenvalue of $\widehat\rho_t$ that can possibly approach $\lambda_1(\rho)$ when $t\to0$ is  $\lambda_1(\widehat\rho_t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly isn't true in general. E.g. suppose $A$ is not a scalar multiple of $I$. Let $x$ be a unit eigenvector corresponding to the *minimum* eigenvalue of $A$. Then $x$ is also an eigenvector corresponding to the *maximum* eigenvalue of $I$. However, given any function $g$ such that $g(t)=O(t^2)$,
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_\max(I+tA)
&=\lambda_\max(I)+t\lambda_\max(A)\\
&>\lambda_\min(I)+t\lambda_\min(A)+g(t)\\
&=\lambda_\min(I)+t\operatorname{tr}(Axx^\ast)+g(t)\\
&=\lambda_\max(I)+t\operatorname{tr}(Axx^\ast)+g(t)
\end{aligned}
when $t>0$ is sufficiently small.

The statement is true, however, when the eigenvalue is simple. If you assume that eigenvalues and eigenvectors are differentiable, the statement follows easily from implicit differentiation. See [user7530's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2588484) for instance.

An elementary proof of a more generalised version of the statement, without assuming differentiability of eigenvalues or eigenvectors, can be found in Stewart and Sun's *Matrix Perturbation Theory*. See theorem 2.3 on p.183. Their proof, when adapted to your case, is especially easy. By a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $\rho=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1(\rho),\ldots,\lambda_n(\rho))$ is a diagonal matrix whose eigenvalues are arranged in ascending/descending order. Now suppose $\lambda_1(\rho)$ is a simple eigenvalue (the other cases can be handled analogously.) The essential idea is to consider the following matrix $\widehat\rho_t$ that is similar to $\rho+tA$:
\begin{aligned}
\widehat\rho_t
&=(tc\oplus I_{n-1})(\rho+tA)(\frac{1}{tc}\oplus I_{n-1})\\
&=\pmatrix{
\lambda_1(\rho)+ta_{11}&t^2ca_{12}&t^2ca_{13}&\cdots&t^2ca_{1n}\\
\frac{a_{21}}{c}&\lambda_2(\rho)+ta_{22}&ta_{23}&\cdots&ta_{2n}\\
\frac{a_{31}}{c}&ta_{32}&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&ta_{n-1,n}\\
\frac{a_{n1}}{c}&ta_{n2}&\cdots&ta_{n,n-1}&\lambda_n(\rho)+ta_{nn}
}
\end{aligned}
It follows that when $\lambda_1(\rho)$ is a simple eigenvalue, then when $c$ is sufficiently large and $t$ is sufficiently small, the radius of each Gerschgorin disc of $\widehat\rho_t$ can be made arbitrarily small. Since $\lambda_1(\rho)$ is different from other $\lambda_j(\rho)$s, the first Gerschgorin disc of $\widehat\rho_t$ is disjoint from the others. But by the continuity of eigenvalues, the eigenvalues contained in the first Gerschgorin disc must approach $\lambda_1(\rho)$ when $t$ tends to zero. Hence that eigenvalue must be $\lambda_1(\widehat\rho_t)$. Now, by Gerschgorin disc theorem,
$$
|\lambda_1(\widehat\rho_t)-\lambda_1(\rho)-ta_{11}|
\le \sum_{j\ne1}|t^2ca_{1j}|
$$
and the result follows.